# Solving for positive reals: $abcd=1$, $a+b+c+d=28$, $ac+bc+cd+da+ac+bd=82/3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, contest-math, roots

$$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$$

$$ a+b+c+d=28$$
$$ ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd=\frac{82}{3} $$
$$ abcd = 1 $$

One can also look for the roots of polynomial

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) \\[4pt]
&= x^4 - 28x^3 + \frac{82}{3}x^2 - (abc+abd+acd+bcd)x + 1
\end{align}$$

and $f(x)$ has no negative roots... but how else do I proceed?

There is a trivial solution $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, 27$. We just need to prove it's unique.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BDiscriminant%5Bx%5E4-28x%5E3%2B82%2F3x%5E2-t*x%2B1%2Cx%5D%3E0%2Ct%5D), the discriminant of $f(x)$ is nonnegative if and only if $$-2749\approx-\frac{4140+896\sqrt{21}}{3}\leq t \leq -\frac{4140-896\sqrt{21}}{3}\approx -11.34\,,$$ where $t:=abc+abd+acd+bcd$.  Note that, in this range, $t$ is negative.  Therefore, your polynomial cannot have four positive real roots.

Comment: @Batominovski This system has unique (with any cyclic permutations) solution: $\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},27\right)$, See please my post.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Dang it.  I mistyped my WolframAlpha query.  I didn't use $\geq$ sign.  That is why the case $t=\dfrac{244}{27}$ was omitted.  See the [corrected WolframAlpha query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BDiscriminant%5Bx%5E4-28x%5E3%2B82%2F3x%5E2-t*x%2B1%2Cx%5D%3E%3D0%2Ct%5D).

Comment: Three equations in general are insufficient to determine four unknowns.

Comment: I agree: three equations in general are not sufficient to determine four variables.

Comment: @WillJagy Well, that's why I said *in general.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $d = \max{a,b,c,d}$. Looking at the inequality:
$$(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$$

**beginning edit by Will:**
from Michael,
$$ 82 = 3 (bc+ca+ab) + 3d(a+b+c),  $$
from displayed inequality
$$  82 \leq (a+b+c)^2 + 3d(a+b+c) $$
$$ 82 \leq (28-d)^2 + 3 d (28-d) $$
$$ 82 \leq 784 - 56d + d^2 + 84d - 3 d^2   $$
$$ 0 \leq 702 + 28 d - 2 d^2 $$
$$ 0 \geq 2 d^2 - 28 d - 702  $$
$$  0 \geq d^2 + 14 d - 351 $$
$$ 0 \geq (d+13)(d-27).  $$
As $d >0$ we get
$$ 0 \geq  d-27 $$
$$ 27 \geq d $$
**end of edit by Will**

will give you $d\leq 27.$ Consequently, $abc\geq \dfrac{1}{27}.$

**SECOND EDIT by WILL**

$$ f = ( ab + bc + ca)^2 - 3abc(a+b+c) $$
$$ 4(b^2 - bc + c^2)  f =  \left( 2 (b^2 - bc + c^2)  a - bc(b+c)    \right)^2 + 3b^2  c^2 (b-c)^2 $$
Conclusion: permute the letters, $ f \geq 0$ and $f \neq 0$ unless $a=b=c.$ Real $a,b,c$ otherwise unrestricted

**END SECOND EDIT by WILL**

From $a+b+c \geq 1$and $abc\geq \dfrac{1}{27},$  we find that $ab+bc+ca\geq \dfrac{1}{3}.$ Then,

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\leq ab+bc+ca = \dfrac{82}{3} - d(28-d)\iff d^2-28d+27 \geq 0$$
This means $(d-27)(d-1)\geq 0$ so $d = 27.$ The rest should follow immediately.

Comment: looking at it. Why does the first displayed inequality result in $d \leq 27 \; ? \;$

Comment: @Will Jagy Because $\frac{82}{3}\leq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}+d(a+b+c)=\frac{(28-d)^2}{3}+d(28-d).$ Beautiful solution! +1

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thank you. getting there, so far $351+14d-d^2 \geq 0.$   If it factors...  Alright, $d^2 - 14 d - 351 \leq 0,$ or $ (d-27)(d+13) \leq 0,$ with positive $d$ we need $d-27 \leq 0$ so $d \leq 27.$  Good.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg edited in your bit.

Comment: @Will Jagy  Now, by AM-GM $ab+ac+bc\geq\frac{1}{3}$ and the rest he wrote.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg in case you are still awake, I also don't see $ab+bc + ca \geq \frac{1}{3}$ based on, it seems, $abc \geq \frac{1}{27}$ and $a+b+c \geq 1$ at that stage.

Comment: Yes, $ab+ac+bc\geq\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}\geq\frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: thanks, this is beautiful

Comment: Ah yes, the trick of making $d$ into a quadratic inequality. I've used that to set problems, and can't believe I forgot about it in this case.

Comment: @calvin lin i actually kept using more advanced inequalities like schur but that didnt work out for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

The hint.

By your work  $$\frac{x^4-28x^3+\frac{82}{3}x^2+1}{x}-\frac{244}{27}=\frac{(3x-1)^3(x-27)}{27x}$$ because by Rolle $$\left(\frac{x^4-28x^3+\frac{82}{3}x^2+1}{x}\right)'=\frac{(3x-1)^2(x^2-18x-3)}{3x^2}$$ has three positive roots and one of them must be $\frac{1}{3},$ which is also an element of $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

Indeed, let $0<a\leq b\leq c\leq d$.

Thus, $f'$ has positive roots on $[a,b]$ on $[b,c]$ and on $[c,d]$ and we know that one of these roots it's double $\frac{1}{3}$.

Let $\frac{1}{3}\in[a,b]$ and $\frac{1}{3}\in[b,c].$

Thus, $b=\frac{1}{3}$, which says $$abc+abd+acd+bcd=\left(\frac{x^4-28x^3+\frac{82}{3}x^2+1}{x}\right)_{x=\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{244}{27}.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Rolle part? I read the wiki and still don't follow. Also how did you come up with $\frac{244}{27}$?

Comment: @Helen The function $f(x)=\frac{x^4-28x^3+\frac{82}{3}x^2+1}{x}-constant$ has four positive roots, which says that $f'(x)$ has three positive roots. Also, $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{244}{27}.$

Comment: @WillJagy There is a trivial solution $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, 27$. So at least it looks reasonable.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks let me digest this...

Comment: @Helen $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{244}{27}-constant=0$. It was typo in my previous comment.

Comment: Didn't you omit the term in $x$ from the polynomial function?

Comment: I cannot understand why $\frac{1}{3}$, which is a root of $f’(x)$, is also a root of $f(x)$. I think that not all roots of $f’(x)$ are roots of $f(x)$ too. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Angelo $f'(x)$ must have three positive roots. One of them it's $\frac{1}{3}$, which is a double root of the derivative. It says that $\frac{1}{3}$ must be one of numbers from $\{a,b,c,d\}$, otherwise $f$ has no four positive roots.

Comment: Why must a double root of the derivative be a root of the function too? I cannot understand it. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @Angelo Just draw it and see my previous comment. It's obvious. Let $0<a\leq b\leq c\leq d$. Thus, we have roots of $f'$ on $[a,b]$ on $[b,c]$ and on $[c,d]$. One of them it's double $\frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: For me it is not obvious. Could you prove it by writing all the steps of the proof?

Comment: @Angelo I added something in my previous comment. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: Thank you for your more detailed proof.

Comment: @Angelo You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Do you know any method of solving this system of equations without calculus?  I tried with standard inequalities, but to no avail.

Comment: @Batominovski I also still don't see. Must be something. Maybe C-S...

Comment: @Batominovski I added a non-calculus approach. There should be a way to play with this using inequalities, but the solution set is throwing me off.

Comment: @Batominovski unless I am grossly mistaken, I added an answer with only basic inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an unsatisfactory answer as I don't expect the discriminant to be calculated in a contest-math setting.]

Let $ C = abc + bcd + cda + dab > 0$.

The equation $ x^4 - 28x^3 + \frac{82}{3} x^2 - Cx + 1 =0 $ has 4 positive real roots.

The discriminant ([Thanks Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant+of+y+%3D++x%5E4+-+28x%5E3+%2B+82%2F3x%5E2++%2B+1+-+cx+)) is

$$\Delta = -5565901568/81 + (82093312 C)/9 + (13588640 C^2)/27 - 74032 C^3 - 27 C^4 \\ 
= -9 ( C - \frac{244}{27} ) ^2(3C^2 + 8290C + 93488). $$

Since the equation has 4 real roots, the discriminant is non-negative.
The only positive value of $c$ which makes $\Delta$ non-negative is $ c = \frac{244}{27}$.

Hence, the solution is uniquely determined (up to permutation).

Comment: I used the same idea when I asked WolframAlpha to do the job.  But I didn't put the query quite right, so initially, I thought there were no positive real solutions.

Comment: Might elaborate a bit on$( a−7)^2+(b−7)^2+(c−7)^2+(d−7)^2 \rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ what does right arrow mean here and where does 7 come from @WillJagy

Comment: @WillJagy I frankly don't know. It's a third-handed source already -- a friend of mine, whose middle school niece is training for math contests. It isn't really that important? It's quite a fun problem anyways.

Comment: @WillJagy but I'm personally interested in your Lagrange multiplier solution, even though the problem is probably intended for elementary solution

Comment: @WillJagy gotta admit I don't exactly follow. If you can write it as an answer, that would be great. If it takes too much time I can understand you'd pass because there is a good chance I still don't follow even if you write it out as an answer. :)

Comment: @WillJagy I did. I learned Lagrange multiplier too. But I really don't follow what you mean by $(a−7)^2+(b−7)^2+(c−7)^2+(d−7)^2 \rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, and where number 7 came from. Also not follow "the whole business can be written over in a rotated basis"

Answer (score 2):

I used letters $w,x,y,z.$ We begin with two constraints, $w+x+y+z=28$  and $wxyz=1.$ When $w,x,y,z > 0,$  the 3-plane $w+x+y+z=28$  intersects the first quadrant in a regular tetrahedron, the center at coordinates $(7,7,7,7).$ The surface (it really is a surface) inside it with $wxyz=1$ is usually just a little bit inside the tetrahedron. We suspect that this surface is tangent to the 2-sphere $$  w+x+y+z = 28 , (w-7)^2 + (x-7)^2 + (y-7)^2 + (z-7)^2 = R^2 $$
for appropriate (positive) $R$ at the known solution points $(1/3,1/3, 1/3, 27)$ and that the surface is otherwise genuinely inside that sphere. This turns out to be true.

The objective function, to be extremized, is
$$ (w-7)^2 + (x-7)^2 + (y-7)^2 + (z-7)^2 = w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 14 (w+x+y+z) + 4 \cdot 49 =  $$
$$  w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 14 \cdot 28 + 4 \cdot 49 = w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 196  $$
so
$$ f = w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 196 $$
is always nonnegative.
Half of its gradient is $(w,x,y,z).$

The constraint gradients are $(1,1,1,1)$ and
$$ (xyz, wyz, wxz,wxy) = (\frac{wxyz}{w},\frac{wxyz}{x},\frac{wxyz}{y},\frac{wxyz}{z})= (\frac{1}{w},\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}) $$

Lagrange multipliers, out of Marsden and Tromba, says the gradient of $f$ is a linear combination of the two constraint gradients,
$$ (w,x,y,x) = \lambda(1,1,1,1) + \eta  (\frac{1}{w},\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z})$$

The equation for $w$ reads $$ w^2 - \lambda w - \eta = 0,  $$ that for $x$ is
$$ x^2 - \lambda x - \eta = 0,  $$ then
$$ y^2 - \lambda y - \eta = 0,  $$
$$ z^2 - \lambda z - \eta = 0.  $$
There can be just two real roots to the quadratic for fixed real $\lambda, \eta.$

Therefore, we have some choices. First, all entries the same, $w=x=y=z,$ but the product must be $1,$ each is one, so the sum would be $4$ rather than $28.$

Next, and this one does occur, we could have two pair, namely $$ (x,x, \frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x})  $$
The product is already $1$ and the sum is $2x+(2/x).$ For this to be $28$ we get
$x^2 - 14x+1 = 0,$ with $x = 7 \pm \sqrt {48}.$ Here the objective function becomes $192,$ the distance from the center is $8 \sqrt 3 \approx 13.8564.$ By permuting, there are six of these points, they are the saddle points very near the midpoints of the tetrahedron edges. Six edges.

Finally, the four points near the vertices and the four points near the (triangular) face centerpoints occur with three entries the same,the other different. I write $$(x,x,x,\frac{1}{x^3}).$$ When the sum is $28$ we get
$$  0 = 3 x^4 - 28 x^3 + 1 = (3x-1)(x^3 - 9 x^2 - 3 x - 1)  $$
The cubic does have one real root, about $9.332923293870422360535874023,$ so a point very near a face centerpoint is about
$$ ( 9.3329, 9.3329, 9.3329, 0.0012301 )  $$
Four of these. The objective function is about $65.310373,$ so the distance from $(7,7,7,7)$ is about $8.08148$

Finally, four points near the tetrahedron vertices,
$$  (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3},27   )  $$
with objective function $1600/3$  and distance from $(7,7,7,7)$as
$$\frac{40}{\sqrt 3}    $$
As you already know, this gives the correct sum of pair products.

In sum, it is only the points near the vertices of the tetrahedron, where the surface is tangent to a sphere of fairly large radius, that answers the original question.

[image]

Comment: I don't find any graphic of a tetrahedron with an appropriate smooth surface inside. Perhaps that task is also better addressed in a rotated coordinate system, which I think could produce a proof by non-calculus inequalities.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up. I believe I get the big picture, and i think this is the more general method to this type of question. I will still need some time to digest the details

Comment: I guess we can simply convert the problem into an optimization setup, by finding a feasibility point of $abc + abd + acd + bcd$ given the constraints. Though that might be too difficult to compute by hands without some transformation like yours

Answer (score -2):

Use Mathematica to directly calculate this equation system, there are 4 sets of solutions that meet the requirements:

[image]

The output solution is only for comparison, not a substitute for theoretical analysis.